# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{x}\ln(2x)\:\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am learning to an exam and stumbled upon this integral.

$$\int \sqrt{x}\ln(2x)\:\mathrm{d}x$$

the result should be $\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x^{3}}\left(\ln(2x)-\frac{2}{3}\right)+C$, but I am still unable to get there… Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Integrating by part you get $\ln(2x)\frac{2\sqrt{x^3}}{3}-\int\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{3}dx$, can you finish it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd start this by substituting $x=y^2$

$$\int 2y^2\ln2y^2dy$$

Now use properties of logarithms.

$$\int2y^2\ln2dy+\int4y^2\ln ydy$$

$$u=\ln y,du=\frac{dy}y$$
$$dv=4y^2dy,v=\frac43y^3$$

$$\frac23y^3\ln2+\frac43y^3\ln y-\int\frac43y^2dy=$$
$$\frac23y^3\ln2+\frac23y^3\ln y^2-\frac49y^3+C=$$
$$\frac23y^3\ln2y^2-\frac49y^3+C$$

Just a little rearranging from here and substituting back for $x$ should get you the right form.

Comment: Gosh, that's so complicated. Thank you Mike.

Comment: @user2932090 No problem.  Actually, the only complicated part was getting it back into the right form.  Actually, I think Claude has the simpler answer here.  It seems that $\sqrt x$ had me needlessly worried.

Comment: @Mike. Thanks ! I must confess that I never "see" $\sqrt x$ but $x^{1/2}$ instead. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's not that.  You often take the derivative of the $x$ terms and $\sqrt x$ has this nasty habit of not going away. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Integrate by parts with $u=\log(2x)$ and $v'=\sqrt x ~dx$. So $u'=\frac{1}{x}~dx$ and $v=\frac{2 x^{3/2}}{3}$.

I am sure that you can take from here.